# Codeigniter 2.1 controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I have conroller `baner`, and when I try to run it (run upload function `http://localhost/010/baner/upload_img`), I got 404 error:

> The page you requested was not found

What is wrong here?

The controller:

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload_Baner extends CI_Controller {

    protected $path_img_upload_folder;
    protected $path_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    protected $path_url_img_upload_folder;
    protected $path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder;

    protected $delete_img_url;

  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();       

        $this->setPath_img_upload_folder("public/img/promotions/");
        $this->setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder("public/img/promotions/thumbnails/");

        $this->setDelete_img_url(base_url() . 'upload_baner/deleteImage/');

        $this->setPath_url_img_upload_folder(base_url() . "public/img/promotions/");
        $this->setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder(base_url() . "public/img/promotions/thumbnails/");
  }

  public function upload_img() {

        //Format the name
        $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $name = strtr($name, 'ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃ Ã¡Ã¢Ã£Ã¤Ã¥Ã§Ã¨Ã©ÃªÃ«Ã¬Ã­Ã®Ã¯Ã°Ã²Ã³Ã´ÃµÃ¶Ã¹ÃºÃ»Ã¼Ã½Ã¿', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');

        // replace characters other than letters, numbers and . by _
        $name = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '_', $name);

        //Your upload directory, see CI user guide
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder();

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPG|GIF|PNG';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['file_name'] = $name;

       //Load the upload library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

       if ($this->do_upload()) {

            //If you want to resize 
            $config['new_image'] = $this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $name;
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 193;
            $config['height'] = 94;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

            $this->image_lib->resize();

           $data = $this->upload->data();

            //Get info 
            $info = new stdClass();

            $info->name = $name;
            $info->size = $data['file_size'];
            $info->type = $data['file_type'];
            $info->url = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $name;
            $info->thumbnail_url = $this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() . $name; //I set this to original file since I did not create thumbs.  change to thumbnail directory if you do = $upload_path_url .'/thumbs' .$name
            $info->delete_url = $this->getDelete_img_url() . $name;
            $info->delete_type = 'DELETE';


           //Return JSON data
           if (IS_AJAX) {   //this is why we put this in the constants to pass only json data
                echo json_encode(array($info));
                //this has to be the only the only data returned or you will get an error.
                //if you don't give this a json array it will give you a Empty file upload result error
                //it you set this without the if(IS_AJAX)...else... you get ERROR:TRUE (my experience anyway)
            } else {   // so that this will still work if javascript is not enabled
                $file_data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                echo json_encode(array($info));
            }
        } else {

           // the display_errors() function wraps error messages in <p> by default and these html chars don't parse in
           // default view on the forum so either set them to blank, or decide how you want them to display.  null is passed.
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('',''));

            echo json_encode(array($error));
        }


       }  

  public function do_upload() {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

            return false;
        } else {
            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            return true;
        }
     }


//Function Delete image
    public function deleteImage() {

        //Get the name in the url
        $file = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $success = unlink($this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file);
        $success_th = unlink($this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() . $file);

        //info to see if it is doing what it is supposed to 
        $info = new stdClass();
        $info->sucess = $success;
        $info->path = $this->getPath_url_img_upload_folder() . $file;
        $info->file = is_file($this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file);
        if (IS_AJAX) {//I don't think it matters if this is set but good for error checking in the console/firebug
            echo json_encode(array($info));
        } else {     //here you will need to decide what you want to show for a successful delete
            var_dump($file);
        }
    }

    public function get_files() {

        $this->get_scan_files();
    }

    public function get_scan_files() {

        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
                basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {

            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $file_name;
            $file->size = filesize($file_path);
            $file->url = $this->getPath_url_img_upload_folder() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->thumbnail_url = $this->getPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            //File name in the url to delete 
            $file->delete_url = $this->getDelete_img_url() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->delete_type = 'DELETE';

            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

       protected function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
             array($this, 'get_file_object'), scandir($this->getPath_img_upload_folder())
                   )));
    }

    public function getPath_img_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_img_upload_folder($path_img_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_img_upload_folder = $path_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder($path_img_thumb_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_img_thumb_upload_folder = $path_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_url_img_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_url_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_url_img_upload_folder($path_url_img_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_url_img_upload_folder = $path_url_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder($path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder = $path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getDelete_img_url() {
        return $this->delete_img_url;
    }

    public function setDelete_img_url($delete_img_url) {
        $this->delete_img_url = $delete_img_url;
    }


}
```

Comment: make your class name and file name `baner` and `baner.php` instead of `Upload_Baner`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is named Upload_Baner so unless you have a route defined that maps baner to upload_Baner this won't work. Does this url work?:

```
http://localhost/010/upload_Baner/upload_img
```

That is what your current controller will map to without the route.

Comment: It is working (this will be one of those days when brain is stuck in infinite loop :D). Thank you for your help :)